# Why doesn't window.getComputedStyle invoke recalculate styles and reflow?

Tags: javascript, dom, repaint, computed-properties, reflow

Look at this example:

```js
const startTime = performance.now();
setTimeout(() => console.log(`taken time: ${performance.now() - startTime}ms`))
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.textContent = `Текст n${i}`;
  window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
}
```

and look at another one:

```js
const startTime = performance.now();
setTimeout(() => console.log(`taken time: ${performance.now() - startTime}ms`))
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.textContent = `Текст n${i}`;
  window.getComputedStyle(document.body).width;
}
```

Differences are minimal: in the first case I just invoke `window.getComputedStyle(document.body)` without getting property, and in the second case I doing it with `width` property. As a result in first one we don't see recalculation styles and reflows but in the second one we see vesa versa situation. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `getComputedStyle(element)` actually returns a ***live*** object.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("div");
const style = getComputedStyle(el);
console.log("original color:",  style.color);
el.classList.add("colored");
// we use the same 'style' object as in the first step
console.log("with class color:",  style.color);
```

```css
.colored {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
```

Getting this object doesn't require that a full recalc is performed, only its `getters` will force it.

But browsers are nowadays even smarter than just that, they won't even trigger a reflow for some properties outside of the CSSOM tree that affects the CSSStyleDeclaration object being inspected.

For instance in the following example we can see that getting the `fontSize` property from the CSSStyleDeclaration of an element that is inside our checker will force a reflow affecting our checker, while getting one form outside won't, because unlike `width`, the `fontSize` property is only affected by ancestors and not by siblings.

```js
function testReflow(func) {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    const elem = document.querySelector(".reflow-tester");
    // set "intermediary" values
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
    elem.style.transition = "none";
    try { func(elem); } catch(err) { rej(err) }
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.01s";

    // if the tested func does trigger a reflow
    // the transition will start from 1 to 0
    // otherwise it won't happen (from 0 to 0)    
    elem.addEventListener("transitionstart", (evt) => {
      res(true); // let the caller know the result
    }, { once: true });
    // if the transition didn't start in 100ms, it didn't cause a reflow
    setTimeout(() => res(false), 100);

  });
}

(async () => {
    await new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res, 1000));
  let styles;
    const gCS_recalc_inner = await testReflow(() => {
    return (styles = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#inner")));
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle inner recalc:", gCS_recalc_inner);
    const gCS_inner_prop_recalc = await testReflow(() => {
    return styles.fontSize;
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle inner getter recalc:", gCS_inner_prop_recalc);
    const gCS_recalc_outer = await testReflow(() => {
    return (styles = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#outer")));
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle outer recalc:", gCS_recalc_outer);
    const gCS_outer_prop_recalc = await testReflow(() => {
    return styles.fontSize;
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle outer getter recalc:", gCS_outer_prop_recalc);  
  
})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
.reflow-tester {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="reflow-tester">Tester<div id="inner"></div></div>
<div id="outer"></div>
```

The same checking for `width` would trigger in both cases, because `width` can be affected by siblings:

```js
function testReflow(func) {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    const elem = document.querySelector(".reflow-tester");
    // set "intermediary" values
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
    elem.style.transition = "none";
    try { func(elem); } catch(err) { rej(err) }
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.01s";

    // if the tested func does trigger a reflow
    // the transition will start from 1 to 0
    // otherwise it won't happen (from 0 to 0)    
    elem.addEventListener("transitionstart", (evt) => {
      res(true); // let the caller know the result
    }, { once: true });
    // if the transition didn't start in 100ms, it didn't cause a reflow
    setTimeout(() => res(false), 100);

  });
}

(async () => {
    await new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res, 1000));
  let styles;
    const gCS_recalc_inner = await testReflow(() => {
    return (styles = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#inner")));
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle inner recalc:", gCS_recalc_inner);
    const gCS_inner_prop_recalc = await testReflow(() => {
    return styles.width;
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle inner getter recalc:", gCS_inner_prop_recalc);
    const gCS_recalc_outer = await testReflow(() => {
    return (styles = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#outer")));
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle outer recalc:", gCS_recalc_outer);
    const gCS_outer_prop_recalc = await testReflow(() => {
    return styles.width;
  });
  console.log("getComputedStyle outer getter recalc:", gCS_outer_prop_recalc);  
  
})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
.reflow-tester {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="reflow-tester">Tester<div id="inner"></div></div>
<div id="outer"></div>
```